# KML PHP parser to INSERT into database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, kml, xml, php

So I have a KML file which has attribute data(Inside the  tag with about 12 data points). This file was generated on ArcGIS. I'm trying to write a PHP script to parse this KML file and insert the datapoints within the ExtendedData tag into a db. How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a high-level answer as you've not given any specifics.

Reading KML is basically the same as XML (KML being a subset thereof).

Some possible resources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342337/parse-kml-file-with-php

http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=71913675

http://web.stefanproell.at/wp/2010/01/parsing-kml-files-with-php/

Then you just take the variable that you've read your data to and output it to the database.

Comment: Hey! That worked. Thank you! Sorry about not being specific, but then my question was very basic to start with. Anyways, Cheers!

I used simplexml_load_file to load the file, the functions after that were pretty easy. Thank you once again.